# jquery ajax call giving error, in conjunction with RESTful API

Tags: jquery, restful-url

I need some help analyzing why the following short jquery code is not working. The ajax call is based off RESTful API and I've confirmed this exact call to work. So there's no backend issues. I'm just concerned with the frontend here, which I lack experience in. I think the following should be fairly straightforward, and I can't see what it is that makes the ajax go to error. Is there something blatantly wrong?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                var data = {};
                data["login_name"] = $("#login_name")[0].value;
                data["password"] = $("#password")[0].value;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://website.com/a/login",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json"
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $("#output")[0].value = JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t");
                }).error(function (a, b, c) {
                    $("#output")[0].value = alert(JSON.stringify(c, null, "\t"));
                });
                $("#output")[0].value = "Sending...";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="value">
        <input type="text" class="value" id="login_name" style="width:350px" />
    </span>
    <span class="value">
        <input type="text" class="value" id="password" style="width:350px" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send Request" />
    </span>
    <textarea id="output" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
</body>
```

I can only suspect that something is wrong with data. I created the above code by modifying some existing code:

```
var data = {};

    $("#fields div.entry").each(function(i,elem) {

        elem = $(elem);

        data[elem.find("input.field")[0].value]=elem.find("input.value")[0].value;

    });
```

the code above was in the original working code which created data, I cannot see how it is different from the data array I created....

Comment: is the api on the same domain as your page?

Comment: @rejj no it's not! I just realized that too. The original page wouldn't work either when its not on the same domain. How do I fix this? I need this code to be working in phonegap.

Comment: The only way to do it is to use jsonp, which requires cooperation from the server side

Answer (score 0):

As a quick guess you can try to add the content-type to the post:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'https://website.com/a/login',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
```